# Retrieve URL with non-english character

Tags: ios, utf-8, nsstring, nsurl, url-scheme

I want to open app from SMS (url schemes). For example, If someone send me text "myapp://abcd" I can open this url with safari and open application with abcd value by [url host]. But, the problem is if it is not english? For example "myapp://สวัสดี" (in thai) or "myapp://おはよう" (in japanese) and i open application with xn--l3c1bib8a0a instead of "สวัสดี".

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" 
                                                    message:[url host] 
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    return YES;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SMS character set is 7-bit and a bit special, so it looks like your service provider is translating international urls to their punycode (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) equivalent...

Comment: Thank you for very much for very fast answer but I still quite blind for what should I do next?

Comment: Thankyou very much, Because of your answer I use keyword punycode and found NSURL+IDN which create by Jorge Bernal solve my problem.